# Using return in ternary operator

Tags: php, conditional-operator

I'm trying to use return in a ternary operator, but receive an error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_RETURN
```

Here's the code:

```
$e = $this->return_errors();
(!$e) ? '' : return array('false', $e);
```

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 31):

This is the correct syntax:

```
return  !$e ? '' : array('false', $e);
```

Comment: I don't think that's the intended outcome from the OP's example. This will return in both cases whereas the OP probably asks how to return just in one of the cases.

Comment: Right but it doesn't work that way.  Something will always be returned with a ternary since it is a statement and cannot be nested in a ternary.

Answer (score 14):

Close.
You'd want `return condition?a:b`

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't work in most languages because `return` is a statement (like `if`, `while`, etc.), rather than an operator that can be nested in an expression. Following the same logic you wouldn't try to nest an `if` statement within an expression:

```
// invalid because 'if' is a statement, cannot be nested, and yields no result
func(if ($a) $b; else $c;); 

// valid because ?: is an operator that yields a result
func($a ? $b : $c);
```

It wouldn't work for `break` and `continue` as well.

Answer (score 3):

No it's not possible, and it's also pretty confusing as compared to:

```
if($e) {
    return array('false', $e);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No. But you can have a ternary expression for the `return` statement.

```
return (!$e) ? '' : array('false', $e);
```

**Note:** This may not be the desired logic. I'm providing it as an example.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible. The following, however, is possible:

```
$e = $this->return_errors();
return ( !$e ) ? '' : array( false, $e );
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Plop,

if you want modify your return with ternary ?

it's totally possible.

In this exemple, i have a function with array in parameters.
This exemple function is used to parse users array.
On return i have an array with user id and user username.
But what happens if I do not have any users?

```
<?php

public funtion parseUserTable(array $users) {
   $results = [];
   foreach ($users as $user) {
      $results[$users['id']] = $user['username'];
   }
  return $results ?: array('false', $e, "No users on table."); // Ternary operator.
}
```

Sorry for my bad english, i'm french user haha.

N-D.

Comment: Your post does not answers the OP question. You should follow the code sample provided by the OP in its question and fix it. Moreover, this question is old and already has many answers. It seems that the OP forgot to accept one of those. But you can try to provide a better answer by adding documentation about the `:?` operator.