# Using ternary for return error handling

Tags: php

I have a function which checks the return value from another function and acts on it. some_function() returns a BOOLEAN.

```
     $check = some_function()
     if ($check === TRUE) {
      return $my_return_val; 
      } else {
      handle_error();
      }
```

Does it make sense to use ternary for this? It seems like the code could be tightened up.

Comment: ternary generally makes things less maintainable.

Comment: @DanielA.White meh.. not really - it's all preference

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266334/using-return-in-ternary-operator-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ternary -

```
$check = some_function() ? $my_return_val : $something_else
```

The only thing that will break your ternary operation is your "handle_error()". I would put that in your `some_function()`