# How can I write echo and return inside of PHP ternary operator?

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-operator

```
<?php
$glass= "water";
$bottol;

if(isset($glass)){
    echo $glass;
}elseif(isset($bottol)){
    echo "Empty Bottol";
}
echo PHP_EOL;
```

Ternary Operator is bellow

```
$demo = isset($glass) ? $glass : $bottol;
echo $demo;
```

But how can I echo the  $glass variable as like as if/else statements inside the ternary operator?? Is it possible? Also, how can I return the $glass variable inside the ternary operator? Like:

```
return $glass
```

Comment: You don't return or echo inside it, you return or echo the whole expression (the result of it).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using return in ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266334/using-return-in-ternary-operator)

Answer (score 0):

> how can I echo the $glass variable

```
echo $demo = (isset($glass)) ? $glass : $bottol;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just simply echo $glass or "Empty Bottol" (you don't mention that testing $bottol is also a requirement, so I'll assume your main goal is to echo "Empty Bottol"), you have a few options that are a bit cleaner:

```
<?php
$glass= "water";

echo isset($glass) ? $glass : 'Empty Bottol';
echo PHP_EOL;
```

It gets even better though, since you're just checking to see if a variable is set. When this is the case you can use the "[Null Coalescing Operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce)" - *Note*: this requires PHP >=7.0

It's like the ternary operator but the lefthand operand checks the variable for null values similar to `isset()`. It's
useful for checking values and assigning default values.

It works by giving you back the variable's value if the
variable *is set/not null*, or conversely, the value of the righthand operand if the variable you're checking *is*
null.

General example:

`$checkthisvariable ?? 'default value';`

For you, this would simply be:

`echo $glass ?? 'Empty Bottol';`

Comment: please double check the $bottol; variable which is never used\

Comment: @jmvcollaborator - I completely forgot to delete that variable from the example :| - thanks for the catch!